# How exactly do I use crispy_addon to prepend a form field?

Tags: django, django-crispy-forms

I'm using Django crispy forms and modelform_factory to generate my form. It looks something like this:

```
ModelForm = modelform_factory(Street)
form = ModelForm(request.POST or None, instance=my_record)
```

Then in the template I run this:

```
{% crispy form %}
```

And it generates my bootstrap4 form exactly as intended. However, I'd like to have a single field in my very long form to have a prepended text (@ for a Twitter handle). In the [documentation](https://django-crispy-forms.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api_templatetags.html?highlight=prepend#templatetags.crispy_forms_field.crispy_addon) it reads:

```
templatetags.crispy_forms_field.crispy_addon(field, append='', prepend='', form_show_labels=True)[source]

Renders a form field using bootstrap’s prepended or appended text:

{% crispy_addon form.my_field prepend="$" append=".00" %}

You can also just prepend or append like so

    {% crispy_addon form.my_field prepend=”$” %} {% crispy_addon form.my_field append=”.00” %}
```

I've tried using this as follows in my template:

```
{% crispy form %}
{% crispy_addon form.url prepend=”@” %}
```

But this returns the following error:

```
Invalid block tag on line 12: 'crispy_addon', expected 'endblock'. Did you forget to register or load this tag?
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to load the tag into your template add the following to the top of your template. The reason being this tag is in a different file to the {% crispy %} tag.

```
{% load crispy_forms_field %}
```

Comment: Ahhh great, such a simple solution! Thanks!